# Instantly redirect to another URL when clicking different URL in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using reactjs and `react-router`, upon loading `http://localhost:3000/data/abc123` in my browser (by clicking the URL sent to me), how can I send `abc123` to the server and then instantly redirect to `http://localhost:3000/game/`? I'm not sure how to do so using `react-router` or where to start.

The use case of this is the user is sent a URL specific to them via email (`http://localhost:3000/data/abc123` where `abc123` is their unique ID). When this URL is clicked, `abc123` is sent to the server, and the user is redirected to `http://localhost:3000/game/` with their very own personal data based off of the server's response of `abc123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, you can render `<Redirect to={"http://localhost:3000/data?" + yourData } />` (you can access the value by the location object, provided by react router, be sure to use connect to get these data) then, in the route that will process the data, you deal with the data and then redirect using the same Redirect component (be sure to render to redirect the user)

you can also use an object instead of providing just the path

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```

Here is some reference, happy coding!
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md